# How do transform a key-value like mysql table into a classic mysql table?

Tags: mysql

I'm sorry if the title of the question is somewhat deceptive, I don't really know how to phrase this.

I have a table like this:

```
+---------+--------+--------+
| name    | key    | value  |
+---------+--------+--------|
| Stephen | Age    | 23     |
| Stephen | Hair   | Black  |
| Stephen | Height | 182    |
| Stephen | Sex    | Male   |
| Sarah   | Age    | 25     |
| Sarah   | Hair   | Blonde |
| Sarah   | Height | 162    |
| Sarah   | Sex    | Female |
| John    | Age    | 21     |
| John    | Hair   | Black  |
| John    | Height | 190    |
| John    | Sex    | Male   |
+---------+--------+--------+
```

I need to produce the following output:

```
+---------+-----+--------+--------+--------+
| name    | Age | Hair   | Height | Sex    |
+---------+-----+--------+--------+--------+
| Stephen | 23  | Black  | 182    | Male   |
| Sarah   | 25  | Blonde | 162    | Female |
| John    | 21  | Black  | 190    | Male   |
+---------+-----+--------+--------+--------+
```

Either with plain sql or in an array/associative array in php. Any ideas?

Comment: Are the values in the key column pre-defined or can there be any number of different values in it?

Comment: @MuhammadHamidRafique For this particular case there are predefined values and all names have the same attributes.

Comment: I added the answer. Let me know if you face any problems. You might want to reword the question and add the pivot keyword in there since that is what you are essentially looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple version with just using case statement like this. (Max is used because of the group by on name and to handle if the same key exists multiple time against the same user)

```
  SELECT
  [name],
  MAX(CASE WHEN [key] = 'Age' THEN [value] END) AS Age,
  MAX(CASE WHEN [key] = 'Hair' THEN [value] END) AS Hair,
  MAX(CASE WHEN [key] = 'Height' THEN [value] END) AS Height,
  MAX(CASE WHEN [key] = 'Sex' THEN [value] END) AS Sex
  FROM **YOUR-TABLE-NAME**
   GROUP BY [name]
   HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN [key] = 'Hair' THEN [value] END) = 'Black';
```

The PIVOT function can also be used to pivot the data based on the "key" column (Age, Hair, Height, Sex), and MAX(value) is used as the aggregate function to handle duplicate values.

```
SELECT
  [name],
  Age,
  Hair,
  Height,
  Sex
FROM (
  SELECT [name], [key], [value]
  FROM **YOUR-TABLE-NAME**
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT (
  MAX([value])
  FOR [key] IN (Age, Hair, Height, Sex)
) AS PivotTable;
WHERE Hair = 'Black';
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Thanks fo the tip, this is a step in the right direction. Any idea how could I filter the results? In my real world scenario the table is very large and selecting all records should be avoided. Let's say I want to select all records is my new table where the person has b
lack hair. How could I achieve that?

Comment: Well, you can simply add a where class to both of these methods. Take a look! I modified the examples to show how to use a where condition.

Answer (score 0):

I you want to dynamically generate the `key` as column, provided that there are possibilities where there are other `key` then the ones in your data sample, you can use `prepared statement` like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT name, ',
     GROUP_CONCAT(
        DISTINCT CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN `key`="',`key`,'" THEN value END) AS "',`key`,'"')
           ),
         ' FROM mytable GROUP BY name;') INTO @sql
  FROM mytable;

SELECT @sql;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Here's a detailed fiddle with tests: https://dbfiddle.uk/h3qcMaNq

*Note: I know that your sample data above might not represent your true table structure but in case you are using `Key` as column name, FYI, both `Key` & `Keys` are [reserved keywords in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/keywords-8-0.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-K). You can use it as column name but you have to always wrap it with backticks(``) when writing queries. I personally don't prefer reserved keywords as column name because I work a bit in `javascript` and uses [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in all of my MySQL codes.*